# PHP Trim() of everything that is not "text"

Tags: php

I have a source of strings that typically looks like this

```
word1   
       phrase with more words than one
             a phrase prefaced by whitespace that is not whitespace in code
    wordX
```

NOTE! The whitespace before the words and phrases comes out as whitespace to the naked eye but is not being trimmed by using "trim()".

Is there any way to use either Trim() or preg_replace() to KEEP the whitespaces within the phrases but trim it outside (which looks like whitespaces but isn't).

EDIT: I have no idea what "char" the whitespacelooking spaces before and after the words and phrases are.

Comment: trim() only clean a string of spaces at the start and the end ... in context trim() has no function ... so you have to use preg_replace() to do this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will replace all whitespace characters (spaces, tabs, and line breaks) to a single space:

`$output = preg_replace('!\s+!', ' ', $input);`

EDIT:

For the first-whitespace, you can either `trim()` it, or use this instead:

`$output = preg_replace('!^\s+!', '', preg_replace('!\s+!', ' ', $input));`

I think it could be done as a single RegExp, if a RegExpu guru manages to do it, I'd want this person to have his answer accepted instead.

Comment: Almost works. It still leaves ONE whitespace-like charachter at the beginning. I can work around it by "ugly coding" i.e. looking at first char and if not recognized as charachter I remove it. But still, would've been nice not to. Thanks still. Best regex I've seen so far to handle this conundrum.

Comment: I admit the question is a bit vague. For example it is not clear if the posted example string should be considered as one string or four strings. (downvote wasn't me, btw)

Comment: @Yoshi Thanks for not downvoting it, I appreciate it. I was a bit shocked when I saw a downvote, I'm happy to see it is not you. To the real downvoter: please explain ?

Comment: I set it to answered since it does help me take care of my problem though still missing just the final touch. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Removed my initial comment, as it seems you really got what Adergaard was looking for. Though I still find the question strangely formulated ;)  (justice-upvoting, as my comment could very well have been the reason you got that dv, sorry about that)

Comment: I downvoted since I agreed with Yoshi, just removed the downvote seeing that this was what OP wanted.